# Support for Java 9 Modules in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1

Tags: intellij-idea, java-9

IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 brings support for Java 9’s new modularity (Project Jigsaw). In this latest version.

i have downloaded 2017.1 but default Java 9 support is missing.

How can i enable Java 9 support in IntelliJ ?

Comment: Have you tried that "prior research" thing, like simply entering the title of your question in google? Try it - you might be surprised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you downloaded/installed JDK 9, defined the JDK in Intellij, set it as your project SDK, *and* set the project's language level to 9 (most of which is documented [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-sdks.html)), you should be ready to go. Regarding the module system, JetBrains has documented how to start using it with IntelliJ [in the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-java-9-module-system.html) and in [this blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/03/support-for-java-9-modules-in-intellij-idea-2017-1/).

One last note: consider updating to 2017.2 to get the newest changes.

Comment: Also, if the project is maven-based, then you can just set `<source>9</source>` and `<release>9</release>` in pom.xml. After that IDEA should pick the project level automatically.